# Products in report not showing in community

Tags: community, profile, customer-community, custom-reports, system-permissions

in our org we have created a report to show products. in community this report is showing but when opening it, its throwing insufficient privileges error.
Report type is in deployed status.
Report folder is shared with community user.
Field level access is also assigned to community user profile.

Community user able to access products when creating case. also when try to open product by id its showing product layout with all fields in detail page.

only in report products are not displaying. other reports data like cases are displaying in community.

Thanks

Comment: What about report folder access for that community user whom received Insufficient privilege error?

Comment: folder access is also there for community user, in fact community user able to access case report which is in same folder as Product report. only for product report community user getting error

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please add the error snapshot in your question. It's will help community users to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the product object is not reportable in Community. To expose a report in community, sharing rules must be used. Since Product, just like Price Book, do not have OWD default setting (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387988&type=1), the object cannot be set to private. Therefore, product report cannot be exposed on community.

Find the idea here: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWO2UAN/allow-us-to-share-a-price-book-report-to-the-prm-partner-portal-i-need-to-publi